# getSelection e ignorar tags al comienzo de la selección

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo una función para seleccionar texto mediante Js y después incrustarle DIV y dejar un color explícito.

```
if (document.getSelection) {
            var sel = document.getSelection();

            if (sel.toString() === '' || sel.toString() === '') {
                return;
            }

            if (sel.rangeCount) {
                var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange(),
                    newString = sel.toString(),
                    checkEditor = $('.ereader-highlight-editor');

                if (checkEditor) {
                    checkEditor.remove();
                }

                if (checkEditor && $('.ereader-text-editing')) {
                    presenter.$view.find('.ereader-context-content .ereader-context-page span.ereader-text-editing').contents().unwrap();
                    checkEditor.remove();
                }

                var newHighlight = new constructHighlight(sel, e);
                newHighlight.launchEditor();
            }
        }
```

Si tengo un texto como este para seleccionar con tos BRs en medio.

```
<div>Un robot debe proteger su propia existencia, mientras dicha protección no esté reñida ni con la Primera ni con la Segunda Ley.<br><br>—Gracias —dijo Andrew Martin, aceptando el asiento que le ofrecían.<br><br>Su semblante no delataba a una persona acorralada, pero eso era.</div>
```

Después, cuando selecciono un fragmento de texto, añado al soltar el mouse una etiqueta que es un div con un número en la posición esquina superior izquierda.

Cuál es el problema, que si empiezo a subrayar donde están los BR, también me los incluye el subrayado colocándome el div con el número, fuera del subrayado. Pongo una imagen del resultado final.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo hago para que al empezar a subrayar un texto, y comienza este con BRs, estas etiquetas sean ignoradas para que este sea el resultado bueno?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo he solucionado de esta forma:

```
            $(self.span).each(function () {
                // Seleccionamos el subrayado llamado selfSpan
                var selfSpan = $(this),
                    currentText = $(this).html(),
                    dualBr = currentText.substring(0, 8), //Buscamos si hay uno o dos BRs
                    singleBr = currentText.substring(0, 4);

                if (dualBr === '<br><br>') { //recolocamos justo antes del subrayado si hay dos
                    $(self.span).find('br').first().insertBefore($(self.span)); 
                    $(self.span).find('br').first().insertBefore($(self.span)); 
                } else if (singleBr === '<br>') { //o si hay un BR
                    $(self.span).find('br').first().insertBefore($(self.span)); 
                }
            });
```